# I need to attach an XML file to a SOAP object working with SAAJ in Java 7

Tags: java, xml, soap, saaj

I am using SAAJ with Java 7 to create and send SOAP messages.  I have everything set except for the body.  I need to get the contents of an XML file into the body of the SOAP message without any formatting errors.  I have tried using a DOM document, I've tried reading it in line-by-line with a scanner and manually adding it, but none of them work.  The DOM document solution ended up merely deleting the header and body of the message and my other solution keeps overwriting the "<" and ">" characters with "<" and ">" respectively.  I've tried using String.replaceWith() to hack this but the change is happening as the SOAP message is sent.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this without having to code a giant parser that will create SAAJ objects from xml files?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple test works for me:

```
import org.junit.*;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;

/**
 *
 * @author gpeche
 */
public class SAAJTest {

    @Test 
    public void testAddDocument() throws Exception {
        String xml = "<a><b><c>hello</c><d test='attrib'>foo</d></b>blablabla</a>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
        body.addDocument(doc);
        message.saveChanges();

        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><a><b><c>hola</c><d test="attrib">foo</d></b>blablabla</a></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 SOAPMessage message = getSoapMessageFromString("<a><b><c>hello</c><d test='attrib'>foo</d></b>blablabla</a>");

 private static SOAPMessage getSoapMessageFromString(String xml)
        throws SOAPException, IOException {

    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a new message object with default MIME headers and the data
    // from the XML string we passed in
    SOAPMessage message = factory
            .createMessage(
                    new MimeHeaders(),
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset
                            .forName("UTF-8"))));
    return message;
}
```

if you've already parsed the xml text into a string object and don't care about parsing or validating it.